# I want to count different strings from a column in excel and print it

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

My excel sheet has order of T-Shirts. Column F contains the Size of T-Shirts, i.e S, M, L, XL, XXL. I want to count the number of each type of shirt and print them somewhere on the sheet for the order to be placed. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new sheet with in the first column the possible sizes. Using the [COUNTIF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) function you can then count how many times every size occurs in that column.

More specific, if your first sheet is called "Sheet1", and if you placed the sizes in column A of another sheet. The code would result in: `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!F:F,CONCATENATE("=",A1))` or short `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!F:F,A1)` for the value of B1. You can then just drag that formula over the other rows.

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer. I'm used to using this method because then you can easily customize the `=` in `<` and such